# Get TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code:-

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Get the following error:-

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
at ServerResponse.sendFile
```

Comment: The error message says it all. Provide the absolute path!

Comment: or specify root to res.sendFile

Comment: In which I add specify root??

Answer (score 7):

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile
You either need to specify the full path to "index.html" or do something like

`var options = {'root':<your_root_directory>};
res.sendFile('index.html',options);`

Comment: If you feel that this answer helped you, you could [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an absolute path or specify root to the `sendFile` if you want to work with the relative path.

**Absolute Path**

Provide an absolute path like `E:\\myProj\\static\\index.html`.

**Or Provide Root like**

```
res.sendFile('index.html',{ root: "E:\\myProj\\static"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the above answer provided by 'in need of help', I followed the link to https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile where sendFile options are described.  After copying the code from their example, I learned that "path" requires importing and in a separate answer at [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947942/referenceerror-dirname-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope-building-script/73948058#73948058) discovered that "--dirname" needs to be constructed before the folder to my HTML files can become defined in a relative URL.

Added the following code to my index.js file:

```
// start express requires sendFile() path options to be defined 
import path from 'path'
import url from 'url'
const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
let sendFileOptions = {
  // where second parameter below ('views') is the folder where files 
  // which are to be sent, are located within root of my ExpressJS app
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
  dotfiles: 'deny',
  headers: {
    'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
    'x-sent': true
  }
}
// end express sendFile() options
```

And now in my Express.js request functions, I call on the sendFileOptions as follows:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).sendFile('404.html', sendFileOptions)
})
```