# ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope building script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, dirname

Im having a problem with
"ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope" error

```
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import Layouts from 'vite-plugin-vue-layouts'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Unocss from 'unocss/vite'
import { campaign } from './package.json'



export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/': `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`,
    },
  },...
```

Can anyone provide a solution?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

As the error suggests, `__dirname` is not defined in the ES module scope.

Try this:

```
import url from 'url'

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
```

Now you can use `__dirname` in `path.resolve()`

Comment: Still getting the same error :(

Comment: Where did you write the code I gave in my answer?

Comment: import on top, defined var under all the imports

Comment: Try this:
function dirname(meta) {
    return new URL("", meta.url).pathname;
}


const __dirname = dirname(import.meta);

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/': `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`,
    },
  },...

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'node:path' but you are on to something!

Comment: Update your node version. 
Delete the file package.json, the folder node_modules, and then write 'npm install'

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update Node to the newest version. Vite dropped support for older ones. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding links to change logs that document the change.

Comment: how new is new? I'm on v18.9.0 and still getting this

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the issue and recently installed `module-alias` Uninstalling `module-alias` and removing its related contents will fix the issues.